# jQuery.ajax() omits "empty" object attributes

Tags: jquery

I have the following JS object:

```
var data_test = { foo: [], bar: [ 'baz' ] };
```

When I submit this object via `jQuery.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data_test
});
```

It turns out only the `bar` array is sent, and not the `foo` one.

Proof: In *test.php* I simply `var_dump`ed the `$_REQUEST`:

```
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "baz"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to force jQuery to also submit an empty object attribute? I need jQuery to send an EXACT copy of the `data_test` object, if it omits empty value that breaks my logic!

Comment: [This is intentionally so.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6481) There is no jQuery way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it, or is there something else I should do since there is no solution for my question?

Comment: Exactly my situation! For me at the back end, the property identifies a table and the attribute carries the criteria that an SQL query should apply on the table. If the criteria is an empty array, jQuery does not send it like your case and therefore, for me, that table  is not queried breaking my logic!

I solved it by using the value as null or "". Either way, the back end receives "" and luckily my back end language, php, allows the array subscript operator, [] applied on a string with each application find nothing resulting is querying the table without a criteria as my logic requires.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A little (very) late to the game, but I wanted to point out that if your application is ready to accept JSON, you can send empty arrays using JSON.stringify:

```
var data_test = { foo: [], bar: [ 'baz' ] };

$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data_test),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

This should post the empty array. Beware that `JSON.stringify` is available starting from IE8, but you could always use [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to fill this gap.

Answer (score 0):

why not just set the empty array .... you can even make a function this way....

```
function __validate(obj) {

 for(key in obj) {

  if(obj[key].length == 0) {
    obj[key] = [""];
  }

 }

return obj;
}

data_test = __validate(data_test);
```

Now , if you will see , you will get the exact structure .
Yet as @lonesomeday correctly said, there is no jQuery way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will have to look into changing my application around this fact now.